# Event target should be anchor but is image instead

Tags: javascript

I am working on a dialog script in Vanilla JS. I ran into a problem with the click event on the video image. Even tough the image is surrounded with an anchor tag it shows the image as the event.target on the "trigger-dialog-open" event.

Here is the HMTL:

```
<a class="trigger-dialog--open thumbnail" data-dialog-id="dialog-video" href="javascript:;">
    <figure>
        <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/id/sddefault.jpg" alt="" />
    </figure>
</a>
```

And this is the event in JS:

```
var openTriggers = document.getElementsByClassName('trigger-dialog--open');
for (var i = 0; i < openTriggers.length; i++) {
    openTriggers[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        this.openDialog(event.target.getAttribute('data-dialog-id'));
    }.bind(this), false);
}
```

The event handler wants to know the dialog-id from the anchors data attribute. It can't be found because it thinks the image is the event.target, not the actual anchor. How can I correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget). The `event.target` is supposed to be the `img` element since that is what the user has clicked on. The click then bubbles up through the image's containers. `event.currentTarget` gives you the element that the click handler was actually bound to.

(Or if you didn't bind `this` to some other object you could use `this` within the click handler and it should also be the current target.)

Comment: Thanks this does work! Although not in IE < 9 I think.

Comment: I assumed you weren't worried about IE < 9, because you're using `addEventListener()` - which doesn't work in IE<9 either...

Comment: Yeah. Actually, I was reading about addEventListener not being supported by IE8 this very day :) Not happy about that. I am considering adding html5shiv to the site.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me tons of time. Could not figure out why I was not getting the element the event was bound to. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

I have a few questions is the **var openTriggers** supposed to be a part of a module hash? Because if it's global then you don't use a **this**, you only add a **this**, if it's referencing a variable that the function is also contained in. For example:

```
var aThing = {
   openTriggers: document.getElementsByClassName('trigger-dialog--open'),
   openModal: null,
   openDialog: function(clickedThingAttr){  
     if(this.openModal !== null){ 
        this.openModal.style.display = 'none';
     }else{ 
        this.openModal = document.getElementById(clickedThingAttr);
     }
     this.openModal = document.getElementById(clickedThingAttr);
     this.openModal.style.display = 'block';
   },
   setEventListenersNStuff: function(){
     for (var i = 0, n = this.openTriggers.length;i < n; i++) {
         this.openTriggers[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            this.openDialog(event.target.getAttribute('data-dialog-id'));
         });
       };
    }

   };//end of aThing hash object
   aThing.setEventListenersNStuff();
```

There are a few issues here:
 1. why are you using **.bind** I think that is a jQuery thing, you want to pass a string to another function when an object is clicked, there no need for binding at all. 
2. Also make sure that if you want to do something like open a modal, there is no need to call another method unless it's kinda complex. 
3. What about other potential dialogs, it seems that when a **.trigger-dialog--open** is clicked you're just showing that one one modal with the embedded id, but what about others? Make sure all modals are closed before you open a new one, unless you want to have like 10 modals are open.

A thing to note: I added the line **var i = 0, n = openTriggers.length;i < n; i++**, now in this case it's silly optimization, and I heard for modern browsers this doesn't apply, but to explain why I added it, is because i < openTriggers.length would count and integrate the array N times. (This may be an outdated optmiziation).

**If you meant global**

Below I added a different set of code, just in case you meant that  **var openTriggers**  is global, kinda like you wrote above. Also I used querySelectorAll for this which is like jQuery's **$('.thing')** selector.

anyhoo, I also added

```
var openTriggers = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-dialog--open');
var n = openTriggers.length;
function openDialog(ddId){ 
  for (var i = 0;i < n; i++) {
    openTriggers[i].style.display = 'none';

  };
  document.getElementById(ddId).style.display = 'block';
};
for (var i = 0;i < n; i++) {
    openTriggers[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
       openDialog(event.target.getAttribute('data-dialog-id'));
   });
}
```

}

So for the question of hiding already open modals I would suggest you could either cache the open Dialog within a module, or you could toggle a class, which would be less efficient since it would require an extra DOM search. Additionally you could add a if this.openModal.id ===  clickedThingAttr to hide if open, that way you got a toggle feature.

Anyways I suggest you read up on this stuff, if you want to use plain JS but would like the features of jQuery: http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/63383858003/how-to-forget-about-jquery-and-start-using-native

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code. Always nice to have some one share some tips. I am using .prototype to mimic a class structure. The reason why openTriggers is in the class var this is because when I call new Dialog() if check if there are triggers at all. If so, then do stuff like bind the events. Every dialog has a it's own template in the HTML. With a unique ID. I simply add the id in the trigger link to a data attribute so it knows what dialog to open. On closing the dialog I look for the dialog class that also has an is-active class. Then close that one.

Comment: Hi Floris, if i could suggest an optimization, when you look for the class that has an **is-active**, you're having computer search the DOM every time to find it. It's best to cache the button or the modal that is open or has been clicked so it can just change the state right away. If you wanna make mini modules like my [survery module](https://github.com/MKwenhua/petecvHeroku/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/survey.js) In some says each Modal acts sort of a class, and if you'd like you could have a parent controller that these modules can **this** from

Comment: You mean when a dialog gets triggered somehow saving that in a class var as being the active one?

Comment: yes, assuming by class you mean local variable in the module. I actually put it in my example it's the variable called **openModal** which is initially set to null.

Comment: Thanks. Very elegant improvement. Made my dialog.js 23 lines shorter ^^

Comment: does that me I can get my first top answer?

Comment: *"1. why are you using .bind I think that is a jQuery thing"* - Without it the call to `this.openDialog()` won't work because `this` will have the wrong value, and no, it's nothing to do with jQuery's `.bind()` method which does something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure

```
var openTriggers = document.getElementsByClassName('trigger-dialog--open');
for (var i = 0; i < this.openTriggers.length; i++) {
    (function(element) {
        element.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            element.openDialog(event.target.getAttribute('data-dialog-id'));
        }, false)
    })(openTriggers[i]);
}
```